# Level Selector Map

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, game-engine

For my animation project I am doing a Unity 3D Game, I have created a **level selector screen** in unity, the problem is that now i need to ***connect the previous level with the next level*** that will be unlocked, so they may be connected at first by a line (or a path) and afterwards the path will become another color (meaning that he can go to the next level). What I want to achieve is something like this (in terms of UI):
[image]

Comment: please simplify you question and plz let people know that where are you stuck what have you done some trails and error Kindly Remember This is not a freelancer portal **so help us help you**

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class `Level` and inside the class you can put variable `X` holding the same `Level` class.
This creates kind of a tree. Then you can say if the current `Level` object is completed, if yes, unlock another `Level` in the tree by pointing on that variable `X`.

You can design the level selector then by working with the object `Level` and its parent object `Level`, getting their position to draw the line etc.

Comment: thank you for the reply ! I have already implemented the unlocking part of the level selector screen, I am stuck on **how to make some dots** along the first levelButton1 and the second levelButton2, that would signify that the level is completed;

So right now all I have are to plain buttons that can get unlocked, but they aren't connected to one another

Comment: Ok, sorry I don't know much about Unity so I won't help you with the actual rendering. But with this way, you can easily point on level UI rectangle and its next level UI rectangle, get their position and draw the lines from these values.

Comment: You can create dots as group of dots saved as png image or by instantiating dot by dot (maybe animate them a lil). Also if your level progress is linear you can just simply remeber value of the highest reached level. And based on that number make lines.